# Working in ADF with Multiple Mappings for one Output

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm currently running into an issue with ADF regarding input files with multiple schema. My tables all contain the data for different days, but there are typos in the column headers, which is messing up my mapping in the long run.

For the sake of troubleshooting, let's say I have 5 files, data1.xlsx, data2.xlsx, data3.xlsx, data4.xlsx, and data5.xlsx.

The first 3 files have the column names of 'ID', 'First Name', 'Last Name', and 'Date/Time'
The last 2 files have the column names of ' ID', 'First Name', 'LAST NAME', and 'Date/Time'

The new space in the ID column, along with the new capitalization in the Last Name column, causes the last 2 files to fail to load in my mapping.

Since I want to load this data into SQL, I want to remove the special character, so my expected output column names would be 'ID', 'First_Name', 'Last_Name', and 'Date_Time'

I'm currently exploring using the lookup function to grab the incoming schema from each file in a foreach statement, but I'm not sure how to get the output mapping with lookup. I had attempted to use the column numbers for mapping (the columns, even if named differently, are always in the same order), but I couldn't find any resources on that.

Any and all suggestions are appreciated, the only other solution I've found is to program an Azure Function, which I hope isn't necessary for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dataflow to achieve your requirement. Copy activity will give the column missing error for the above scenario. Also, coming to lookup approach, rather than giving mapping by looping through every file, you can do the same with a single dataflow.

For sample I took 3 files with different headers (with typos) like below.

```
Sanple1.csv - ID,First Name,Last Name,Date/Time
Sample2.csv -  IDvdgdgvv,First Name,LAST NAME,Date/Time
Sample3.csv - ID,First_Name,Last_Name,Date_Time
```

Now, give the wild card path in the dataflow Source options.

[image]

Click on import projection and this will import the projection of any of the 3 files. But it merges the 3 files data with that header.

[image]

Now, in sink mapping of the dataflow, change the column names as per your requirement of the target table header.

[image]

Here, I have used csv sink, for you it will be your target SQL dataset.

**Result with correct header:**

[image]

Comment: Hey, thank you for the contribution, I really like your answer. I did find a less efficient solution that is working though, I've posted it below.

Comment: Hey, please disregard my previous comment, I do NOT have a solution. 
I wanted to ask a few follow up questions if that is alright.
I'm unable to select my data source when creating the dataflow, does it need to be in a datalake? Because I've been unable to move it into the datalake bc of the same issues causing me to be unable to move it into SQL.

Comment: @Jwest, 'I'm unable to select my data source when creating the dataflow' - what does it mean? and what is your source files location?

Comment: Hey, sorry for the extremely late reply. I have no idea why I'm just now getting the notification. I don't remember the problem as it's been months, but if I recall correctly, it just refused to let me enter in my data source.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting because I found a solution to my issue. Since the column order never changes in my excel files, I just turned 'first row as headers' off, mapped the column numbers to the right column names in sql, then ran a script after my copy statement to delete all rows from the sql table where the id = the word 'id'. It's not perfect but it's working.

EDIT: Always triple check your data, I just realized my data did NOT have matching columns.